# iOS IAP cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, app-store, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

We are stuck for weeks now.

We keep getting the following error when we try to test pay() (using inapppurchase plugin for cordova) for an IAP in the App store:

> RMStore: unknown product id com.company.appname.myID

We've tried every single way get it working with no avail. After several calls with Apple **useless** support, they just keep responding this (when we try to submit the app):

> We found that your In-App Purchase product(s) exhibited one or more
>   bugs, when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.1.1 and iPhone running iOS
>   10.1.1.
>
> IAP inactive

The irony is that the IAP is "Ready to SUbmit" and support said that for **Sandbox Testing** it does not matter what the status of the IAP purchase is.

It works perfectly in the Play Store.

**Update (no fix yet):** [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/196636)

**Update 2:** Might be related to this: [RMStore: invalid product with id myID #181](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/issues/181)

**Update 3 -**
**From Apple Support:**

Nov 22 19:29:57 iPhone itunesstored(iTunesStore)[102] : ISStoreURLOperation: Making POST request, with service type: 0, for URL: https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/inAppCheckDownloadQueue

This log statement tells me that the code is calling the addTransactionObserver method.

Like you’ve I’ve verified that the fetchSfotwareAddOns call is not present in the log.

So at this point, the question - why is the call not happening. Does your code make the SKProductsRequest call, or is this supposed to happen in the RMStore framework. I suspect that the call must be made in the framework. Do you have the source to the framework - if so, what triggers the log statement

If you don’t have the sources, I think your next step is to contact the RMStore development team for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this problem, it's not an issue with RMStore. I added additional logging to RMStore.m and realized the product list is empty, so nothing to do with product identifiers.

You need to have a 'Paid Applications' contract in iTunes Connect for your Paid products to appear. To do this go to your iTunes Connect homepage and select 'Agreements, Tax, and Banking'. Fill out your Contact, Bank and Tax info. Submit the form and wait 15 minutes for contract to process.

A good way to test is to add a free consumable product, this does not need a 'Paid Applications' contract.

Comment: what do u mean by RMStore? would u please tell me? thanks

Comment: The plugin uses the following library: https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/blob/master/RMStore/RMStore.m

You can add logging to that class in your project for more in depth logging. More than likely your app products are not fully set up in iTunes Connect

Did you follow the steps above for the contracts and forms required? Did you try with a free consumable product?